# Define input and target for ann in matlab

Tags: matlab, input, target

I am getting confused about Inputs data and target data. I am studying about Artificial Neural Network in Matlab. I have a data sheet as [Column1-Date| Column2-Tidal Range] I wanted to use the history data (I have Tidal Range data for the past 20 years) to predict Tidal Range in the future (for example 2040). So, what is my inputs and targets?

I have tried using the year as input and tidal range as target and the predictions seems off.

Comment: Hi Zuly, any chance for readers to assess your MATLAB code? you may edit your question and include the lines of code you suspect need a fix. Thanks for your understanding